# Volumes directory in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I just started using Mac OS X. Under the root directory `/`, there is a folder named `Volumes/`.

When I go under the directory `Volumes/`, there is a directory named `Macintosh HD/`. When I go under the directory `Macintosh HD/`, I come back to the root and I can go under the `Volumes/` directory again. If I keep on doing this a few times and check the directory I am at by using pwd, I see that I am in a directory named `/Volumes/Macintosh/Volumes/Macintosh/Volumes/Macintosh`.

I am not able to understand the logic behind this. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, just understand that the `/Volumes/` directory is where *all mounted volumes* on your Mac OS X system naturally show up. And the reason you see that behavior happen is because `Macintosh/` is just a symbolic link to `/` (root) on your system; that is done in `/Volumes` so you still have named access to that volume in addition to the `/` (root) access to that volume.

For example, if you went into the Terminal on your system, typed `cd /Volumes` and then typed in `ls -la` you might see something that looks like this:

```
drwxrwxrwt@  7 root  admin   238 Sep 13 23:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  29 root  wheel  1054 Sep 13 01:43 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     1 Sep 13 16:42 Macintosh -> /
```

A symbolic link is basically like an alias in the Finder; but on a file system level a symbolic link is what an “alias” is.

As for why you see it do that `/Volumes/Macintosh/Volumes/Macintosh/Volumes/Macintosh` in `pwd` that’s just the file system interpreting your path. Yes, it can seem weird and confusing but don’t be confused. The only mounted volume under `/Volumes/` that behaves that way is the root (`/`) volume of your system. If you mount any other volumes, they will show up in `/Volumes/` and will not loop like that since they will be actual, mounted volumes and not symbolic links.

Now as for the “why” of that nested symbolic link/directory behavior, that is not an easy question to answer. But basically all Linux/Unix systems behave like that. And [this question and answer thread on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79571/symbolic-link-recursion-what-makes-it-reset) does go into some extreme detail as to why you nested directories caused by symbolic links exist.

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you. One last question: What does the directory (not the symbolic link) Machintosh HD as below mean? Is this similar to the root on a windows machine? <br/> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    1 Sep  9 00:13 Macintosh -> /  <br/>
drwxr-xr-x  3 ht88  admin  102 Sep 13 23:58 Macintosh HD

Comment: no it all make sense, thank you. It turns out I created that directory as I was fiddling around.

Comment: @HusT: Keep in mind that when another volume is mounted, `/Volumes` is the system default folder where you'll see this new drive. You can direct a volume to mount a different folder from the command line but PnP will use `/Volumes`